# OpenGL constructing and using data on the GPU

Tags: c++, opengl, gpgpu

I am not a graphics programmer, I use C++ and C mainly, and every time I try to go into OpenGL, every book, and every resource starts like this:

```
GLfloat Vertices[] = {
some, numbers, here,
some, more, numbers,
numbers, numbers, numbers
};
```

Or they may even be vec4.

But then you do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
        make_vertex();
```

And you get a problem. That loop is going to take a significant amount of time to finish- and if the make_vertex() function is anything like a saxpy or something of the sort, it is not just a problem... it is a big problem. For example, let us assume I wish to create fractal terrain. For any modern graphic card this would be trivial.

I understand the paradigm goes like this: Write the vertices manually -> Send them over to the GPU -> GPU does vertex processing, geometry, rasterization all the good stuff. I am sure it all makes sense. But why do I have to do the entire 'Send it over' step? **Is there no way to skip that entire intermediary step, and just create vertices on the GPU, and draw them, without the obvious bottleneck?**

I would very much appreciate at least a point in the right direction.

I also wonder if there is a possible solution without delving into compute shaders or CUDA? Does openGL or GLSL not provide a suitable random function which can be executed in parallel?

Comment: "Then you do this", do what? A loop that does something? What does it do? And shader doesn't run once per vertex, it might run multiple times. And do you really have to ask if it's better to run in parallel on the GPU than serially on the CPU? It's quite unclear what you're after here

Comment: I thought it was pretty clear, but I have edited it. As for what it does, is not really important. The loop itself is inefficient and silly. And if I am gonna pick the wrong tool to do the job of completing that loop, I may as well just ignore the parallelism of the GPU in it's entirety at this point and just draw serially, and get the exact same effect. So hence my question. How do I do all of this on the GPU.

Comment: At some point both the CPU and GPU need to know about the vertices.  OpenGL supports the creation of the vertices on the CPU and then moving them to the GPU.  If you create them on the GPU using something like CUDA you would probably end up copying them to the CPU eventually.  Since the CPU is what guides the GPU is makes sense to start the data on the host.

Comment: @FestivalofAsh: "*As for what it does, is not really important.*" No, it very much is "really important". Since what's going on behind that function, and the reason you have such a loop at all, vital to knowing if such a thing can even work on the GPU. I, for one, have never written such a loop. And I have seen very few OpenGL learning materials that have such a loop either. And even when they do, more often than not, they don't run *every frame*. So your question seems poorly thought out and researched.

Comment: @NicolBolas So how do you pick out random vertices if you don't use a loop like that? The only thing it does is take time. And after that time, it has to be sent over PCI-E, which is pretty good, but still, we are talking vertices, not chars. All I want to do is move the vertex figuring out to the GPU. I don't mind sending it back to the CPU after it is done, _efficiently_.

Comment: @FestivalofAsh: "*So how do you pick out random vertices if you don't use a loop like that?*" I don't render "random vertices", and very few other people do either. The vast majority of stuff that gets rendered is built in modelling packages and loaded into an application from some file format. "Vertex figuring out", for most people, happens in an off-line tool.

Comment: @NicolBolas So what do you do when you want to draw fractal terrain, or anything that does not happen in off-line tools, without needing to write 1000 line code of just vertex data? I thought it was a given that you would have a container of some sort to store vertex data, created on the fly, to be then processed by a fragmentation shader. I should've pointed this out in the question, but I thought it was a given- it is not the fragment shader that will slow the operation down, it's the CPU crunching the vertices.

Comment: @FestivalofAsh: Vertices are not "processed by a fragmentation shader". Vertices are processed by a vertex shader. Fragments are processed by a fragment shader. Rasterization transforms primitives into fragments, and it happens between them. And unless you're generating those vertices every frame, the CPU will not be a bottleneck.

Comment: @FestivalofAsh: I think you're suffering mostly from misconceptions how GPUs process input data into pictures. The fragment shader is at the far end of the pipeline and its purpose, boiled down in essence, is to determine the color to give the final pixels in the rendering. However depending on the task at hand the fragment shader might be the right place to do something very complex but only very little everywhere else. It really depends on the problem.

Comment: @FestivalofAsh: "*I'll admit that I cannot, physically, follow OpenGL books, references or tutorials, that start with the first code-snippet, depicted, and continue to use it well beyond a point where it stops being useful.*" That right there is your problem. You're trying to find code that fits your preconceived notions and are becoming frustrated because it doesn't exist. When learning something new, it is best to drop *all* preconceptions and just learn what the lesson has to teach you.

Comment: @FestivalofAsh assuming that your loop is used to generate the terrain, you definitely shouldn't be running it every frame. If there's no existing software that generates the terrain for you, you should just run that loop, generate the terrain vertex buffer, but instead of rendering it, dump the vertex buffer to the disk or something. Have a separate OpenGL "viewer" program that reads that vertex file straight into the GPU, and just render that without terrain generation every frame

Comment: @NicolBolas Ok, bud, you seriously need to stop with your own misconceptions. It was a faux pas. I am not stupid, I know how the pipeline works. And if I want to do math at any stage, the fragmentation one is that stage. None of this has any relevance to my question. Do I need CUDA or does openGL have some functionality, that no book I know describes, to do what I want to do, which is very clearly described in my OP. And just in case, I'll copy-paste the essence of it: "Is there no way to skip that entire intermediary step, and just create vertices on the GPU, without the obvious bottleneck?"

Comment: @AlexYan What if the camera moves though? That was my original plan. At first I figured I'd just have a texture, and perform functions in the fragmentation stage- but it just doesn't seem right. For example, if I wanted an infinite terrain, or a binary tree that goes into infinity-- how would I go about handling that? Is there no way to do it in a... I dunno, I suppose per pixel way? I am out of my depth here, but something like a raymarch that instead of checking the height, determines the height at each step.

Comment: @FestivalofAsh: "*What if the camera moves though?*" You "know how the pipeline works", but you don't understand the concepts of object transformations, model space, camera/eye space, and the like? All those tutorials that gave you headaches were trying to teach you something. Something that you clearly haven't learned. Also, the term is "fragment shader", not "fragmentation stage."

Comment: @FestivalofAsh I'm pretty new to graphics, but I think what you're asking for could work by generating height maps with a compute shader, and mapping that onto a grid with fixed spacing which can be generated trivially. That's a possible solution off the top of my head. You can use GL Compute shaders, OpenCL, or CUDA. Details can be generated with geometry and tessellation shaders. Not sure why all your math is inside the fragment shader though because vertex transformation/generation takes place in vertex, geometry, and tessellation shaders

Comment: As for preventing the camera from clipping, you'd probably have to use transform feedback and do a check per frame to see if the direction you're moving in will intersect the geometry. That's my guess. I haven't gotten far enough in my graphics adventures yet to know how to work with transformation feedbacks

Comment: @NicolBolas I never said I did. And no, it's actually called 'Fragment Processing'. Thanks a lot for not answering my questions, bud.

Comment: @AlexYan So I have to generate with a compute shader? I figured that would be the case, but I was really hoping openGL would just have a method of generating random vertices, which I could then manipulate, without employing the CPU in the crunching process. But come to think of it, if I used a bunch of triangles to make a quad, I could randomize the height and use fragment shaders for.. actual color, and that doesn't involve CPU crunching. Post it as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: @NicolBolas Nicol, I am sorry about what I said. I understand you were trying to be helpful and I acted out of line. I also really like the tutorial on that bitbucket. It is exactly what a learning material should be like and I wish you linked me to that. Fixed-functionality is exactly why I skipped pages. Again, I appreciate your help, and apologize for acting in a childish manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use CUDA for the things you are used to do in C or C++, and let OpenGL access the rasterizer and other graphics stuff.

OpenGL an CUDA interact somehow nicely. A good entry point to customize the contents of a buffer object is here: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__OPENGL.html#group__CUDART__OPENGL_1g0fd33bea77ca7b1e69d1619caf44214b , with cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer method.

You may also want to have a look at the nbody sample from NVIDIA GPU SDK samples the come with current CUDA installs.

Comment: Oh, that is brilliant and exactly what I want! The registertexture is also very appealing!

Comment: @FestivalofAsh, I am glad it answers your question. You may want to accept it (or another) to mark the question as answered so that other readers get the information before reading all the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're asking for could work by generating height maps with a compute shader, and mapping that onto a grid with fixed spacing which can be generated trivially. That's a possible solution off the top of my head. You can use GL Compute shaders, OpenCL, or CUDA. Details can be generated with geometry and tessellation shaders.

As for preventing the camera from clipping, you'd probably have to use transform feedback and do a check per frame to see if the direction you're moving in will intersect the geometry.

Answer (score 1):

Your entire question seems to be built on a huge misconception, that vertices are the only things which need to be "crunched" by the GPU.

First, you should understand that GPUs are far more superior than CPUs when it comes to parallelism (heck, GPUs sacrifice conditional control jumping for the sake of parallelism). Second, shaders and these buffers you make are all stored on the GPU after being uploaded by the CPU. The reason you don't just create all vertices on the GPU? It's the same reason for why you load an image from the hard drive instead of creating a raw 2D array and start filling it up with your pixel data inline. Even then, your image would be stored in the executable program file, which is stored on the hard disk and only loaded to memory when you run it. In an actual application, you'll want to load your graphics off assets stored somewhere (usually the hard drive). Why not let the GPU load the assets from the hard drive by itself? The GPU isn't connected to a hardware's storage directly, but barely to the system's main memory via some BUS. That's because to connect to any storage directly, the GPU will have to deal with the file system which is managed by the OS. That's one of the things the CPU would be faster at doing since we're dealing with serialized data.

Now what shaders deal with is this data you upload to the GPU (vertices, texture coordinates, textures..etc). In ancient OpenGL, no one had to write any shaders. Graphics drivers came with a builtin pipeline which handles regular rendering requests for you. You'd provide it with 4 vertices, 4 texture coordinates and a texture among other things (transformation matrices..etc), and it'd draw your graphics for you on the screen. You could go a bit farther and add some lights to your scene and maybe customize a few things about it, but things were still pretty tight. New OpenGL specifications gave more freedom to the developer by allowing them to rewrite parts of the pipeline with shaders. The developer becomes responsible for transforming vertices into place and doing all sort of other calculations related to lighting etc.

> I would very much appreciate at least a point in the right direction.
>   I am guessing it has something to do with uniforms, but really, with
>   me skipping pages, I really cannot understand how a shader program
>   runs or what the lifetime of the variables is.

uniforms are variables you can send to the shaders from the CPU every frame before you use it to render graphics. When you use the saturation slider in Photoshop or Gimp, it (probably) sends the saturation factor value to the shader as a uniform of type float. uniforms are what you use to communicate little settings like these to your shaders from your application.

To use a shader program, you first have to set it up. A shader program consists of at least 2 types of shaders linked together, a fragment shader and a vertex shader. You use some OpenGL functions to upload your shader sources to the GPU, issue an order of compilation followed by linking, and it'll give you the program's ID. To use this program, you simply `glUseProgram(programId)` and everything following this call will use it for drawing. The vertex shader is the code that runs on the vertices you send to position them on the screen correctly. This is where you can do transformations on your geometry like scaling, rotation etc. A fragment shader runs at some stage afterwards using interpolated (transitioned) values outputted from the vertex shader to define the color and the depth of every unit fragment on what you're drawing. This is where you can do post-processing effects on your pixels.

Anyway, I hope I've helped making a few things clearer to you, but I can only tell you that there are no shortcuts. OpenGL has quite a steep learning curve, but it all connects and things start to make sense after a while. If you're getting so bored of books and such, then consider maybe taking code snippets of every lesson, compile them, and start messing around with them while trying to rationalize as you go. You'll have to resort to written documents eventually, but hopefully then things will fit easier into your head when you have some experience with the implementation components. Good luck.

**Edit:** 
If you're trying to generate vertices on the fly using some algorithm, then try looking into [Geometry Shaders](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader). They may give you what you want.

Comment: I very much appreciate the explanation. I did not consider the filesystem at all, I did say I skipped a lot of the pages, but I did compile all of the code, and made my own, and really, my only issue was with when I got to defining points, and there was a lot of them, and I had to apply functions to them, performance would take a huge hit. I'll keep trying though, and implement CUDA or a compute shader, as the other answer suggests.

Comment: @FestivalofAsh That's how things works though; you upload your buffers for storage until you issue the draw call. How much time it takes to load points from a file them shouldn't matter this much, as you're supposed to do it in the loading stage and not in-between frames. If you're generating your vertices with an equation or similar, then try looking into Geometry Shaders; an optional stage where you can choose to "emit" more vertices on the go on the GPU for processing. If you're still going with a GPGPU approach, then consider using OpenCL over CUDA since the latter is exclusive to NVIDIA.

Comment: indeed, I looked over the pipeline again, and realized I could use a single vertex, and then do things either in the geometry shader stage, or fragment shader stage. The funny thing is, I *knew* it worked like that, I just did not realize it. But the fragment shader uses _fragments_ not vertices. I feel silly for even saying this, but I don't know how I ended up confused like this. Still, I'd like to take a GPGPU approach, so I don't end up writing huge shaders.